# Ebean : @Formula annotation

Tags: annotations, ebean

I m using ebean in my playframework project and i know that i must use the Formula annotation :
[http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/annotation/Formula.html][1]
but the document wasn't of great help.
Could someone give me a better explanation about the transcient annotation and the sql formula.